# How can I read many large .7z files containing many CSV files?

Tags: pandas, csv, dataframe, dask, 7zip

I have many `.7z` files every file containing many large `CSV` files (more than 1GB). How can I read this in python (especially pandas and dask data frame)? Should I change the compression format to something else?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be able to open the file using

```
import lzma
with lzma.open("myfile.7z", "r") as f:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, ...)
```

This is, strictly speaking, meant for the `xz` file format, but may work for 7z also. If not, you will need to use libarchive.

For use with Dask, you can do the above for each file with `dask.delayed`. 
`dd.read_csv` directly also allows you to specify `storage_options={'compression': 'xz'}`; however, ramdom access *within* a file is likely to be inefficient at best, so you should add `blocksize=None` to force one partition per file:

```
df = dd.read_csv('myfiles.*.7z', storage_options={'compression': 'xz'},
                 blocksize=None)
```